# Field of vision - Objective-c

Tags: collision-detection, objective-c

Here's where I'm at.

[image]

Here's where I want to be

[image]

Here's how it's drawn

```
SKShapeNode *fov = [SKShapeNode node];
UIBezierPath *fovPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[fovPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[fovPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(fovOpposite *-1, fovDistance)];
[fovPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(fovOpposite, fovDistance)];
[fovPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
fov.path = fovPath.CGPath;
fov.lineWidth = 1.0;
fov.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor];
fov.antialiased = NO;
fov.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
fov.alpha = 0.2;
fov.name = @"playerFOV";
[_playerImage addChild:fov];
```

Now, I'm not expect the answer of "use this code" I'm hoping someone can point me down a logical path of determining how to `emit` the field of vision, and if it encounters an obstacle, it stops drawing.